# Ubuntu Theme can't be installed by terminal

Tags: 16.04, themes, ppa

I trying to install Ubuntu theme from here:
http://www.noobslab.com/2016/02/make-your-gnome-desktop-to-look-like.html

All commands are successful executed from command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install humanitary-gtk-theme
```

As far as I understand, theme should appear in Appearance menu, or Unity Tweak, but it does not. Here is my Ubuntu version:

[image]

So, the version meets theme's requirements.

So, is there any way to solve this question?

If it is not, there is some temp folder where Ubuntu saved theme files? 
Because I really liked that theme. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unknown reason, many themes don't appear in **Unity Tweak Tool**. I suggest using **Gnome Tweak Tool** instead. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

You can then change the theme.

Alternatively, you can use terminal to change theme.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Humanitary'
```

will set the theme.

To go back to default theme, You'd use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Ambiance
```